# EventSource in Angular 6 with JWT - 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: angular, jwt, event-sourcing, eventsource, http-status-code-406

I would like to detect events from a URL address in my web application. I implemented it with Spring (backend) and Angular (frontend).

I use JWT to sign in.

In one of the components, I want to check if a POST method was sent by some user (to check if a notification was added to a database via POST mapping) for example `http://localhost:8080/notifications`.

So, in another component: `TaskComponent` I created EventSource object, on the basis of: https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/ in this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const eventSource = new EventSource(http://localhost:8080/notifications', {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken')
    });
    console.log(eventSource);
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken'));
}
```

Login and `sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken')` work fine, but after the opening `http://localhost:4200/task` I get `406` code, even though I'm logged in the app, which is related with `notifications` REST API.

Comment: isn't it something related to ur server side program?

Comment: If I'd known, I'd have resolved it :) So, I will look for a solution in the controllers and secutiry configuration...